# react-image-magnify doesn't work properly when zooming when mixed with Tailwind

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, magnify

I am using Tailwind and react-image-magnify, and the image zoom is not working correctly. And when I don't use Tailwind, it works properly. Attached are screenshots of the correct and incorrect behavior.

Correct (Without using Tailwind): (https://i.stack.imgur.com/gn1zn.jpg)
Incorrect (Using Tailwind): (https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSU8p.jpg)

here is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactImageMagnify from "react-image-magnify";

const ImageView = () => {

    return (
        <ReactImageMagnify
            {...{
                smallImage: {
                    isFluidWidth: true,
                    src: `https://placeimg.com/640/480/any`,
                },
                largeImage: {
                    alt: "",
                    src: `https://placeimg.com/640/480/any`,
                    width: 2640,
                    height: 4480
                },
                isHintEnabled: true
            }}
        />
    )
}

export default ImageView;
```